# Logout and click on back button redirect to page issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel when i logout and click on back button it goes back to page from where i logout.

I think its `issue of flush session data` so i have used below method to flush session data and redirect to login page.

I have removed this line `Artisan::call('cache:clear');` for clear cache is well.

```
public function getLogout()
{
        $this->auth->logout();
        Artisan::call('cache:clear');
        Session::flush();
        return redirect('login');
}
```

this are libraries i have also used :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Lang;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Session;
```

I think session is not clearing data or redirect issue.

Comment: Do you mean after pressing back you can still access the page you logged out from ? If so make sure that the page route is protected by the 'auth' middleware.

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#protecting-routes

Answer (score 0):

here is the original function called behind the scene :

> inside
>   **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticateUsers.php**

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

you need to override this function in your LoginController, if you want to do customization.

Comment: Yes i have override this is `LoginController` but no luck still as i click on back button it redirects to last accessed page before logout,still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
 public function __construct() {
    //Log out Back
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');      
}
```

This code should be on base controller.

Comment: I used  above code in my `LoginController` but still no luck

Comment: @raju_eww Not in the login controller but in the controller from where you have clicked logged out. Suppose you are in profile page. Then you have to put that snippet of code on profile controller and try to logout from that url. It should work. good luck :)

Comment: But i have logout as common in header so i have to put it for all controllers?

Comment: try to put in one and see if that works. then you can put it on base controller from where all controller extends.